# I want to use some packages from ubuntu to alpine

Tags: docker, ubuntu, alpine-linux

I have a docker file of alpine image with Python. It has flask, json etc. I want to add numpy and rasterio packages to the docker file. The ones I found on docker hub or online only had packages for Ubuntu, but I need them for alpine image. Please suggest

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk add python3 py-pip && pip install flask flask_json flask_cors 
requests pymongo 


WORKDIR /source
COPY . .
ENV FLASK_APP app.py
ENV FLASK_ENV development
EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["python", "-m", "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

I want to add these to the docker file:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install python-numpy gdal-bin libgdal-dev
$ pip install rasterio
```

Answer (score 0):

`ppa` is ubuntu personal package site, it afford deb package, you can not use it in alpine. Use next to find the one in alpine:

```
orange@orange:~$ docker run -it alpine /bin/sh
/ # apk update
/ # apk list | grep numpy
py2-numpy-f2py-1.16.4-r1 x86_64 {py-numpy} (BSD-3-Clause)
py-numpy-f2py-1.16.4-r1 x86_64 {py-numpy} (BSD-3-Clause)
py-numpy-doc-1.16.4-r1 x86_64 {py-numpy} (BSD-3-Clause)
py3-numpy-1.16.4-r1 x86_64 {py-numpy} (BSD-3-Clause)
py-numpy-1.16.4-r1 x86_64 {py-numpy} (BSD-3-Clause)
py-numpy-dev-1.16.4-r1 x86_64 {py-numpy} (BSD-3-Clause)
py2-numpy-1.16.4-r1 x86_64 {py-numpy} (BSD-3-Clause)
py3-numpy-f2py-1.16.4-r1 x86_64 {py-numpy} (BSD-3-Clause)
```

And according to [this](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/testing/x86/gdal), gdal is in edge testing source, then you also need to add it to apk list.

So according to above methods, finally a workable Dockerfile as next:

```
FROM alpine

RUN echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk update && \
    apk add python3 python3-dev py3-numpy py-numpy-dev gdal gdal-dev build-base musl-dev && \
    pip3 install rasterio flask flask_json flask_cors requests pymongo
```

With above, you can add other things to it to form your final dockerfile.

Comment: `atline` can you please elaborate on the edge testing source part? Can I directly use the docker file above?

Comment: @last_unknown gdal only in edge. yes you can

Answer (score -1):

There's absolutely nothing wrong with using an Ubuntu-based Docker image.  It will come in somewhat larger than an Alpine-based image, but this space difference isn't usually significant.

Also note that there's an [official Docker Hub `python` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/) with various versions of the interpreter preinstalled, based on both Debian and Alpine.  (You may need to [install `software-properties-common` to use `add-apt-repository` on a Debian base](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45879/how-to-add-repository-from-shell-in-debian).)  So the easiest Dockerfile that has Python 3 preinstalled, and can run those APT commands, might look like

```
FROM python:3-stretch
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install gdal-bin libgdal-dev
WORKDIR /source
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
ET cetera
```

where [the `requirements.txt` file lists out all of the Python packages you need to install](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#requirements-files), exactly the same as you'd use in your non-Docker virtual environment that you use for day-to-day development.

Comment: Thanks `David Maze` I tried using an Ubuntu image as well but it took very long time to build, and in the end it failed due to some dependency. The python3-stretch dockerfile that you shared looks good, I can check that. thanks again